# Is there a hierarchy of power among humans,Devas and Gods?

Tags: gods, human

In Greek mythology, humans sometimes defeat Gods - for example, in the Trojan war, the Greek hero Diomedes is said to have wounded goddess Aphrodite and even the God of war, Ares himself.

Are there examples from Hindu scripture, when ordinary (not avataras or half-divine beings like Arjuna)  humans defeat Devas or Gods?

Comment: how do you know for sure that diomedes was not half-divine or an avatar ?

Comment: Muchukunda?....